# nginx, rails and ruby-debug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ruby-debug

I recently shifted my application from `apache2` to `nginx`, and since then I face a peculiar problem with `ruby-debug`. When execution hits a debugger call, and ruby-debug is not running, it causes my system to crash.

This problem has cropped up after switching to nginx, I never had this on apache.

Im using Ubuntu 11.04. Any inputs on what could be the cause would be much appreciated.